# Select by attributes and delete selected records with arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

Got 11 Tables exported to gdb from excel files.

Those Tables have the same structure (same fields) but different data.

Records from the Tables contain useless data which needs to be deleted in the script process.

In ArcGIS Pro I delete that useless data with the Select by Attributes tool:

```
Select [Where] [FieldName] [contains the text] [uselesstext]
```

And then delete the selected records.

But I need to put this process into the script though can not find the proper code or hint to create the function.

Updated code:

```
import arcpy
import re
fc = r'D:\YourFolderName\YourGDBName.gdb\YourFeatureClassName'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "YourFieldName") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if re.match(r"YourWordHere.+", row[0]):
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

This code works when searched word stands at start of the field.

```
import arcpy
import re
fc = r'D:\YourFolderName\YourGDBName.gdb\YourFeatureClassName

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "YourFieldName", where_clause="YourFieldName LIKE '%YourWordHere%'") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.deleteRow()
```

This code works with a word at any part of the field.

Comment: I guess here is not really newbie friendly environment... :) what I need is to get proper WHERE clause for LIKE command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if row[0] is LIKE regist%` is not a valid python code, you can't use SQL syntax directly like this. Instead, try to rephrase the condition with python syntax. For example:

```
import re

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "owner") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if re.match(r"regist.+", row[0]):
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Another option is to put the SQL-like condition in the UpdateCursor itself:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "owner", where_clause="owner LIKE 'regist%'") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Both codes work with a small correction. In definition, instead of row[0] must be row, otherwise, it returns with NameError: name 'row' is not defined. I will update my initial sample code now with the correct versions. Unfortunately, I can not upvote since it needs "at least 15 reputations" and I got 0 :)